# Importing class from another file executes some code outside of the class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to import a class from another file. This is the class file:

```
// homeTask.ts

export class HomeTask extends ITask {
  
  run = async (): Promise<Record<string, any>> => {
    //some method logic...
  }
}

new HomeTask().init()
```

The `ITask` is an abstract class which has the `init()` method in it.

This line in the file is outside of the class, however it seems that when I'm importing the class it's executes this line as well, even if it outside of it:

```
new HomeTask().init()
```

I'm importing the class like this:

```
import { HomeTask } from '../tasks/homeTask'
```

I don't want this line to run so any ideas why this is happenning?

Comment: The file has to be executed for the class to be defined and exported. If you don't want the other line to run when the file's executed, it shouldn't be at the top level

Answer (score 0):

The entirety of the other module is executed when you import it.

If you don't want a

```
new HomeTask().init()
```

to run, remove it, or e.g. move it into a function; assuming it's e.g. for a test, you could move it to

```
export function test() {
  new HomeTask().init()
  // probably something else...
}
```